# Using a JQuery .animate to change a div from 0px to 450 px in height, but the process creates an unwanted margin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have been trying to create a collapsible footer with JQuery. I've got all the animation function working together, however, the animate function that operates on the div (id=draw) creates something that behaves like a margin underneath it (but doesn't appear in any style attributes or computed attributes).

It just pushes any object below it down by the same height as the animated css height value I use.

Code used:

```
    $("#close").hide();
$("#open").click(function () {
  $("#draw").animate({height:"450px"},"slow");
  $("#container").animate({top:"-450px"},"slow");           
  $("#open").hide();
  $("#close").show();
     });
$("#close, .shadow").click(function () {
  $("#draw").animate({height:"0px"},"slow");
  $("#container").animate({top:"0px"},"slow");
  $("#open").show();
   $("#close").hide();
     });
```

For a better idea of what i'm describing check out http://365Designs.com/contact and click on the "open" in the footer.

I'll be so grateful for any help.

Revision:
Sorry, didn't quite make my intentions clear, I actually want the main container div to move up like that (or at least to create the same effect), so that the page above disappears off the page in proportion to the newly created div height at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're animating the main container div 450px up. If you scroll to the top of the page after you click, you'll see it isn't there. Remove that line of code and it should be ok.